# In R's officer package, can you add a microsoft shape to a PowerPoint slide?

Tags: r, officer

I'm using the officer package in R, and I have a lot of charts on a slide. To break up the slide, I want to add a shape in between them (think, a long narrow rectangle). I know I could save something as an image and put it in, but this code is meant to be shared broadly. Thus, it'd be much easier if I could tell R to use a PowerPoint shape rather than upload my own image.

Is this possible? Or, is there some other workaround that doesn't involve creating a custom shape, saving it as an image, and uploading it from my computer?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How much have you already created in officer. Does everything exist already and you are trying to add just the shape?

Comment: @MrFlick, there's nothing to add--I just want to know how to put a shape on a blank slide.

Comment: This is also my question but I cant an answer for it. it's supposed to be a very basic feature